# Algorithm to find the optimal line among 2D - point cloud

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, least-squares

I am asking the community after some time trying to find an algorithm that could produce some *median/optimal continuous line in a cloud of point* as the one there.

[image: cloud point]

I tried this paper's algorithm

[Total least squares fitting of Bézier and B-spline curves to ordered data
[CF Borges, T Pastva]](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=5e3a850cf840be76bd1f3ad10ddc28c9f6f648d5)

but isn't quite producing what I expect and rather the two contours somehow connected. I was wondering of any better solution than filtering out points ?

Thanks,

Edit:

The ordering of the point was really the problem. For this example, in which the two series of points are generated as a dilatation with r<1 and rotation of the larger circle.

[image: ordering effects]

Indeed reordering the input points so that they are ordered clock-wisely by the above-mentioned algorithm produces the results I am expecting.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: What line would you want the algorithm to output for the above figure?

Comment: One line that minimize distance to all points to some sense. It has to describe a single curve too and not both contour somehow connected/

Comment: Does a least squares regression do what you need? If not, why not?

Comment: Are you trying to find a line (as in your question) or a curve (as in the paper you tried)?